# Select a div insinde another div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, jquery-selectors

So I try to select a div within another div. My html goes like this:

```
<div id="Stage_game_page1"><div id="cube0">[...]</div><div id="cube1">[...]</div></div>
```

I want to select my #cube0 within my Stage_game_page specifically, with jQuery or JS.

The goal of the selection is to use it in an loop.

I tried :

```
var count =$("#Stage_game_page").children().length;
for(i=0; i<count;i++){
    $("#Stage_game_page")$("#cube"+i)[...]
   }
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It doesn't answer your problem but...Ids should be unique to the document, you really shouldn't be duplicating them.

Comment: oups, typing error, one cube is #cube0 and the other is #cube1

Comment: If they're unique why do you care about where they exist in the hierarchy?  You can just omit the #Stage_game_page selector.

Comment: Hmm why not `$("#Stage_game_page").children().each()` where the `this` will be the cude instead of `for`?

Comment: What is it that you're wanting to do inside of this loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
var count =$("#Stage_game_page").children().length;
for(i=0; i<count;i++){
    $("#cube"+i);
   }
```

This is sufficient to select the "#cube0"/"#cube1"/"#cube2" etc. especially since ids are always unique. To answer the question  `$("#cube0", "#Stage_game_page")`... that is how you select a div in another div

Answer (score 1):

The id attribute should only be used once!  I see above that you're using id="cube0" twice.  If you want your divs to be recognized in multiple instances, use a class instead (the . instead of the #).  Using the same id twice will probably break your script.

I believe for your html, you could use id "cube0", "cube1", etc., as long as you're ok with entering them manually.  That should work for the loop you'd like to use.

Answer (score 1):

Loops through each div that starts with the id `cube` inside `Stage_game_page1`

```
$("#Stage_game_page1 > div[id^='cube']").each(function () {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f45z1fh3/)

[Child Selctor](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

[Starts with Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for loop.

```
$('#Stage_game_page1').children().each(function(index) {
  // your code here with index starts from 0
});
```

or this using [jquery attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('#Stage_game_page1').find('[id^="cube"]').each(function(index) {
  // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) or [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) or the like.

Answer (score 0):

The correct jQuery usage would be

```
$("#Stage_game_page").find('#cube'+i)
```

to find a div with that id inside the container `#stage_game_page`

Comment: Isn't it a little pointless to have a fast ID lookup *inside* another fast ID lookup? That actually slows down the search. `$("#cube"+i)` does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate cube0 in your html code..

and i think the look should contain something like that:

```
$("#cube"+i)[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

One another solution is:

```
$("#Stage_game_page1 div[id='cube0']")
```